# RSA KEY Encryption/Decryption Problem

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider, aspnet-regiis.exe

I tried

> C:\dev>aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" -exp
>   Creating RSA Key container...
>   The RSA key container could not be opened.
>   Failed!

and

> C:\dev>aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "ASPNET"
>   Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container...
>   The RSA key container was not found.
>   Failed!

Both failed. Any idea?

Comment: probably a privilege issue, but the documentation I was looking at was indecipherable.

Answer (score 0):

In general when we have had to generate these keys we have needed somebody who had admin level permissions to generate the said key.